# Why am I allowed "direct access" to an object's protected field, whose class is defined inside a different package?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

Main.java, main package:

```
package pkgs.main;
import pkgs.test.B;

// Just some method inside the "main class"
void method() {
    B b = new B();
    b.x ++;  //   <--- why is this allowed?
}
```

A.java, main package:

```
package pkgs.main;

public class A {
    protected int x;
}
```

B.java, test package:

```
package pkgs.test;
import pkgs.main.A;

public class B extends A {
}
```

**Edit:**

Another way of looking at this issue is as follows.  I'll add two extra lines of code to the existing example code:

Main.java, main package:

```
// Just some method inside the "main class"
void method() {
    B b = new B();
    b.x ++;  //   <--- why is this allowed?

    b.y ++;  //   (Additional code) Compilation ERROR, which is correct.
}
```

B.java, test package:

```
public class B extends A {
    protected int y;  // (Additional code)  protected field;
                      // access to it is disallowed inside the 
                      // "main calling class" above.
}
```

Comment: That should not be allowed. Can you show your actual class. Don't skip the class declaration, although you can skip some unwanted methods. I'm still sure that you should not be able to access protected fields like that.

Comment: @RohitJain OP declared as `public class B extends A` So protected field of `A` allowed for `B` right (Since it is child) ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ AFAIK, the access is only allowed through inheritance, and not directly using reference of type `B`. So in class `B` you can access it like `this.x++`, but not like `new B().x++` from anywhere outside.

Comment: @RohitJain, I've double-checked my code, and it all works.  There's so little that I omitted.  Simply, just the main(...) method call to that void method()!  BTW, I think that all answers so far have misinterpreted my question.

Comment: @RohitJain, for completeness, here is the rest of the "main calling class": class Main {
 static public void main(String args[]) {
  new Main().method();
 }  // (etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“direct access” to an object's protected field is allowed in this particular example case, because the protected field declaration was made in a class that resides inside the same package as the "calling code".  I guess Java doesn't look to see in which package the field is actually being used (ie inside a different package *via inheritance*).  Java is only interested in the location where the field is originally declared.

Answer (score 2):

Since B extends A , protected fields allowed access to it's children also.

> > The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Please prefer to read  [`Controlling Access to Members of a Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------

protected   Y      Y        **Y**           N
```

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes. I just did it :)

Comment: I thought that once a protected field was inherited, that field becomes private to all "outside callers".  Yes, it can be inherited again by another sub class, but when I access the protected field in my example code, I am not using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misunderstood the concept of "protected".

The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, **by a subclass of its class in another package**.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)